# Using an If Statement in Argument Default Value

Tags: r

I was wondering if it's legal to have an if statement in the default value of an argument.

For example:

```
foo <- function(x, description=if(x>0) "pos" else "non-pos") {
  cat(x, description, "\n")
}
```

The function runs successfully and does what you would expect:

```
> foo(1)
1 pos
> foo(-1)
-1 non-pos
```

But, when debugging it interactively, I get a *'promise already under evaluation'* error when trying to access the `description` argument multiple times:

```
> debug(foo)
> foo(1)
debugging in: foo(1)
debug at #1: {
    cat(x, description, "\n")
}
Browse[2]> description
debug at #1: [1] "pos"
Browse[3]> description
Error: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Thanks

Comment: This is definitely allowed - plenty of functions in the major packages use if statements in default arguments. No idea why it's causing that error though! Usually that error would be if you tried to have x=x as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the prompt:  `Browse[2]` the first time, `Browse[3]` the second time.  What's happening is that you are single stepping through the expression that sets the default value of `description`, i.e. `if(x>0) "pos" else "non-pos"` and haven't returned yet.  When it prints

```
debug at #1: [1] "pos"
```

it isn't printing the value of `description`, it's printing the statement that's about to be executed.

If you hit return (or `n` to go to the next statement), you get the 
`Browse[2]` prompt again and things are fine:

```
> foo(1)
debugging in: foo(1)
debug at #1: {
    cat(x, description, "\n")
}
Browse[2]> description
debug at #1: [1] "pos"
Browse[3]> 
[1] "pos"
Browse[2]> description
[1] "pos"
Browse[2]>
```

Changing your function to

```
foo <- function(x, description={if(x>0) v <- "pos" else v <-"non-pos"; v}) {
  cat(x, description, "\n")
}
```

will make the steps much clearer.